# AES-128 output bytes in codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, aes

According to the codeigniter documentation, the encryption key for an AES-128 MUST be set to 128bits/16bytes (16 characters) random string. I tested my output using var_dump function

(assuming I have set a 16 character key to the config file and already loaded the library)

My code:

```
$plain_text = 'Hello World';
              $encrypted = $this->encryption->encrypt($plain_text);
              var_dump($encrypted);
              var_dump($this->encryption->decrypt($encrypted));
              die();
```

The output
string(176) (A 176 character encrypted data appears)
string(11) Hello World

Sorry I'm not able to put the exact encrypted data but I believe is doesn't make sense to show it.

I would like to know if the encryption output is perfectly normal output considering its size(176 bytes)

Comment: What is the output of: A 1000 character `$plain_text`? 2000 characters? 3000? Hopefully a pattern emerges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES is a block cipher so [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#Padding) is to be expected.

A block cipher (as opposed to a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher)) can only operate on a pre-determined size and must pad a smaller plaintext in order reach that size before it can operate on it.

With that said, 176 bytes (11 x 16-byte blocks) is a lot bigger than 11 bytes and my guess is that part of the overhead may be because codeigniter encodes its own information (i.e. structured data such as type of variable, length of string, etc.) before encrypting it.

Since you are able to decrypt the ciphertext using the same key, it's probably not a bug in the implementation and is working as intended, though I can't speak for whether it was implemented properly and securely.

Comment: [Not quite](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Encryption.php). It's offering AES-128 in CBC mode with a random IV, properly using HMAC, and base64-encoding the output. For what it's worth `CI_Encryption` is secure, `CI_Encrypt` is not. :)